# python NameError: name 'get_set' is not defined

Tags: visual-studio, python-3.x, intellisense

I searched trough all of the previous error but nothing seems to be close to this.

Intellisense sees my method but i still get the error. I refreshed db and still nothing. It's frustrating that i cant see whats wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The method `get_set` is not defined. I means, you did not created it yet.